# ServiceStack V4 MVC authentication and use of JS client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, servicestack

I have a new MVC4 project installed via the MVC Starer package in nuget. I have configured Authentication via the ORMLite auth provider, with MSSQL as the backing store.

To ensure that the MVC4 project is properly integrated with SS I have [followed this guide](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration). I'm using the method described there to resolve the `AuthenticateService` and post the credentials the user has provided in the UI. Upon successful auth I also set a `FormsAuthentication` cookie to let MVC know that the user has indeed logged in. Browsing the site and fetching stuff from the api via MVC controllers work perfectly fine, however, I would like to leverage the API directly to avoid MVC contoller overhead.

Here comes the funky part though: If I try to access the API methods via the browser (or via jQuery) i'm simply receiving HTTP 302 sending me to `/login`, which ends in a 404 because I have no such page.

If I inspect the cookies sent via Chrome Dev-tools it looks like this (+ some others that have been omitted for brevity):

```
ss-id Ve5wdbKiR5VVlu5uQPjF
ss-opt perm
ss-pid zyvcwXomzufMMfkoEN64
```

So it would seem that auth-details are sent to SS. Then, if I fire up Postman and perform authentication directly against the API (via `POST /api/auth`) Google Chrome and jQuery are able to fetch information directly from the `/api` routes

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out that a function I had created to save some extra data to the session after successful login corrupted the session data leaving me unable to communicate properly with the API via http requests.

Comment: was just banging my head on the table for you :) glad you figured it out